# Angular Link Card

Tags: angular

I have an app, a marketplace. When someone shares a link to a product I want to load a picture of the product and a name. Like when you share a link to a social media post there is a picture and a title. Can I do it with angular, and how do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean a favicon?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen no, a photo of the product. You know when you send a link of a twitter post, for example, if the post has a picture in it the picture will show up

Answer (score 0):

What you search for is called a link preview,

What makes this work is metadata called the [Open Graph Protocol](https://ogp.me/#:%7E:text=Introduction,any%20other%20object%20on%20Facebook.). Facebook launched the Open Graph protocol in 2010,

The Open Graph Protocol allows websites to control what is displayed when a website is shared
example

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

so if you have a link and want to display the preview of it, you just need to load the link and read this metadata values

#### How do you get this metadata from a website?

One way you can use [linkpreview.net](https://linkpreview.net/) API to get what you are looking for

```
export interface LinkPreview {
    title:       string;
    description: string;
    image:       string;
    url:         string;
}
// ... here how to get the linkPreview
getLinkPreview(link:string): Observable<LinkPreview>{
  const url = "https://api.linkpreview.net?key=<enter your key>&q="+link;
  return this.http.get<LinkPreview>(url);
}
```

or if you don't want to use API you can use packages like

1. [@angular-material-extensions/link-preview](https://angular-material-extensions.github.io/link-preview/home)
2. [ngx-link-preview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-link-preview)